# ReactJS: How to rerender component after fetching data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I have a component which displays some data fetched from an external API and saved to localStorage. I have put a fetchData() function that does the job, and I call this function from within componentWillMount(). It looks like this:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  ...

  fetchData() {
    if(localStorage.myData === undefined) {
      fetch(apiUrl,{
        method: 'GET',
        headers: ...
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        localStorage.setItem('myData', data);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // error handling
      })
    } else { return true; }
  }
```

The idea here is to check on every render if the data is set in localStorage, otherwise fetch it, save data and then rerender. However, I can't get it to rerender after the data is stored in localStorage. I have tried using `this.setState({data: data})` instead in the fetchData function, but `this` is undefined.

What am I doing wrong here? Thank's in advance.

Comment: `this` in your class has a different context than the `this` inside of your `then()` function. You'll need to appropriately bind your function used in your then

Comment: or use arrow func

Comment: http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` in your class has a different context than the `this` inside of your then() function. For your particular case, you can do the following

```
 fetch(apiUrl,{
    method: 'GET',
    headers: ...
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    // This now refers to your component
    this.setState({data: data});  
  }.bind(this))
   .catch(function(error) {
    // error handling
  })
```

Or as Utro suggested, you can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that will not create their own context thus allowing you to use `this` appropriately.

```
 fetch(apiUrl,{
    method: 'GET',
    headers: ...
  })
  .then(data => {
    // This now refers to your component
    this.setState({data: data}); 
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // error handling
  })
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! I thought the arrow functions was just a semantically different way of doing the exact samt thing as non arrow functions. This explains a lot.. :)

Answer (score 1):

This object inside .then will refer to object of Promise call not the object of Component.

```
vat that = this;
```

declare some variable of this to that and then you can use

```
that.setState({})
```